# Adding const keyword to an array passed as a parameter to function

Tags: c, pointers

Is there any way that I can add `const` keyword to an array passed as a parameter to function:

```
void foo(char arr_arg[])
```

If I place `const` before `char` (`void foo(const char arr_arg[])`) or after `char`(`void foo(char const arr_arg[])`), that would mean than it's `char` which is constant, not the `arr_arg`.

I have just [read](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/10/21/are-pointers-and-arrays-equivalent-in-c/) that under the hood an array sent as a parameter to function is represented as a pointer, so `void foo(char arr_arg[])` is the same as `void foo(char* ptr_arg)`.
Taking it into account, I may rewrite the function as `void foo(char * const ptr_arg)` for it to be exactly what I want to achieve.

But I want to know if there is a way to add `const` keyword in this declaration `void foo(char arr_arg[])` for it to be the same as `void foo(char * const ptr_arg)` (and **not** `void foo(char const * ptr_arg)` or `void foo(const char * ptr_arg)`)?

I just want to understand if there is a syntax to make `arr_arg` constant with array notation `[]`.

Comment: is there any specific reason you don't want to do `void foo(char * const ptr_arg)`? It's exactly the same syntax everywhere else. You can still do ptr_arg[0] as if it was declared as an array.

Comment: @Hans I just want to understand if it's syntactically possible to do it with array notation `[]`. No specific reason. Just want to clarify if it's possible or not (just to know in the future and not waste time contemplating if it's possible or not again and again).

Comment: I don't think there's any need to declare the pointer itself as const as it will be passed by value anyway. Only if you explicitely want to protect from assigning (the copy of the pointer on the stack) inside of the functions definition.

Comment: May be it's possible syntactically in conjunction with the & (reference) operator. Didn't try that so far, but may be it could matter with fixed length arrays.

Comment: @g-makulik I really don't know where I will need it (if at all). But I'm in the process of learning the stuff connected with pointers. And when I got that I don't understand this part, I decided to search SO (took me half an hour) and then asked.

Comment: Wait, is this question C or C++?  Because as some of the answers have observed, they are _very very different_ in this regard.

Comment: @ovgolovin Good approach ;-), but you'll forget unnecessary things in practice anyway (keeps the brain clear for the really needed stuff upcoming). I can remember situations when I needed to declare const fixed arrays used to represent the processors register set for instance (passed to special functions/vectors hooking processor exceptions).

Comment: I didn't think that it may be different for `C` and `C++`. When it became important I left the tag `C++` (which I use). But it's very good to know about `C` as well (that it wasn't possible, and then became possible with the come of a new C99 standard). I would change tags to `C`, but there are some answers related to `C++`. So I'm thinking to adding `C` tag again. :)

Comment: @Mooing Duck Shouldn't C++ cover the C99 standards? At least C++X11?

Comment: @g-makulik I use Dev-C++. Have just tried `...[const]`. It doesn't work.

Comment: @MooingDuck Tags have changed back! Please, delete your comments below  the answers.

Comment: @g-makulik: No, C++11 added some things that C99 had, but the syntaxes are still different and incompatible.  (_Why do you have both languages again?_)

Comment: @MooingDuck I meant reference to a pointer like `char *& ptr` vs `char* const & ptr`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In C you have to put `const` *between* the `[]`, however strange that might look to an unprepared person

```
void foo(char arr_arg[const]);
```

This is "new" [C99-specific syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99). In C89/90 or C++ there no way to do it with "array" syntax, so you have to switch to the equivalent "pointer" syntax, as suggested in David's answer.

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept the answer in a few minutes (when SO will let me do that). Could you write a few words about what C99,C89/90 are (for those who will be reading this answer, for part of them not to search Google to clarify what they are)?

Comment: @ovgolovin added in C99 in 6.7.5.3p7

Comment: @ovgolovin: Note that the argument is still not an array, but a *pointer*, and that pointer is copied, which means that the original pointer (and array) cannot be changed inside the function. If you are talking about real arrays (rather than dynamically allocated memory), then the array is immutable (the contents can be changed, but the array as a container cannot) so it makes little sense to mark it as `const`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I really don't understand what is the sense of having array `const` (I just asked about syntactic possibility to do that). But if a new standard C99 allows it, it mean there are some reasons to allow to declare the array this way.

Comment: @ovgolovin: As David noted, in this case it is not the array, it is the *pointer* that gets declared as `const`. Firstly, this might be useful when supporting coding standards that require all function parameters to remain unchanged (and possibly explicitly declared as `const`). Secondly, the feature was probably introduced to support other, "more useful" specifiers in this context, like `restrict` and `static`, while `const` just tagged along for the ride.

Comment: @ovgolovin: The standard says that the *type qualifiers* go within the square brackets. `const` is just one of the type qualifiers together with `volatile` (also useless there) and more importantly `restrict` which is the only one that makes sense for the array there. The fact that `const` falls within the same category of *keyword* than `restrict` is what allows for the syntax, useless as it is.

Comment: Hm, naming C99 "new" shows that you have a timing quite different from mine :)

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: I meant it as "syntax that is new in C99, as compared to the original C spec" :)

Comment: Even though Microsoft's MSVC *claims* to be C99 compliant (except for VLAs), I get multiple errors on this syntax.  It is accepted by CLANG and GCC.  Microsoft fails again.

Comment: That is a top-level-const, which is ignored when matching function declarations and definitions.

Answer (score 12):

The first thing is that in your particular signature, the argument is transformed by the compiler into a pointer, so what you have is:

```
void foo( char * arg );
```

Now, there are two entities that can be made const in that signature: the pointer and the pointed type. To make the pointed type can be made const in two different yet equivalent ways [*]:

```
void foo( const char * arg );
void foo( char const * arg );
```

The pointer could be made const with the syntax:

```
void foo( char * const arg );
```

But note that in a function signature, in the same way that `char arg[]` is transformed into a pointer `char *arg`, the top level qualifier is discarded. So from the point of view of the declaration, these two are equivalent:

```
void foo( char * const arg );
void foo( char *       arg );
```

In the definition, the top level const can be use to instruct the compiler that the argument pointer (by value) should not be changed within the function, and it will detect if you attempt to reset the pointer to a different location. But, if only the pointer is const, then the compiler will gladly let you modify the pointed memory. If you don't want the function to change the contents of the array, then you should opt for one of the first two signatures.

[*] I tend to prefer the `char const *` format, as it provides a consistent way of reading types: from right to left it reads: *a non-const pointer to a const char*. Additionally it is simpler to reason about typedef-ed types (by performing direct substitution in the expression). Given `typedef char* char_p;`, `const char_p` and `char_p const` are both equivalent to `char * const` and different from `const char *`. By consistently using `const` on the right you can just blindly substitute the typedef and read the type without having to reason.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in C this is possible since C99:

```
void foo(char ptr_arg[const]);
```

is valid syntax and equivalent to

```
void foo(char *const ptr_arg);
```

More generally the `[]` may contain any type qualifier, `static` and an integer expression. But

> The optional type qualifiers and the keyword `static` shall appear only
>   in a declaration of a function parameter with an array type, and then
>   only in the outermost array type derivation.

that is for the dimension that is equivalent to the pointer declaration.

Comment: @MooingDuck, I never said that it is for C++, by I now emphasize on C. 
And the OP still claims that he is interested in C, too, so this answer does no harm.

Comment: Sorry for mistagging. I just thought it's the same in C and C++. But then when I was asked, I left only C++ (which compiler I'm using now).  But in fact it's very interesting to know about C as well. Now I know that it was impossible and became possible only with the come of C99.

Answer (score 2):

There's several ways in C++, but none are *quite* what you seem to be expecting.

```
//typedef has a very clear intent
typedef char* array;
void f0(const array a) {}

//switch to pointers to sidestep the problem
void f1(char* const a) {}

//references are inherently const
//can't take pointers, but guarantees the size, sometimes nice
//this version obviously doesn't work in C
template<int n>
void f2(char (&a)[n]) {}
```

http://ideone.com/4LvYT

Comment: Isn't `void f0(const array a)` the same as `void f0(const char * a)` (which makes `char` constant, not `a`)?

Comment: nope, `array` is a full type, and `const array` makes a `const` variable of type `array`.  It's a _very_ common trick when passing around function pointers, since otherwise the syntax is unwieldy.

Answer (score 0):

For C++, Mooing Duck's answer using the template is the most straight forward.

If you have C code that is calling a C interface implemented in C++, you are stuck with converting the argument into a pointer argument instead, and making that `const`

If you were to use [Boost's array](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost/array.html) instead of using C arrays directly, then you would be able to make that `const`, although it would also be a template function:

```
template <unsigned N>
void foo (Boost::array<char, N> const & arg) {}
```

The advantage of `Boost::array` is that it gives you the ability to do a light weight allocation of an array off the stack, but be able to fully use STL algorithms that depend upon traits in the container.

Comment: Careful with that second, as it is different than asked for and all the other answers on the page.  The data that the array points at is local, and _also_ const.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I modified the answer to point out the advantage of using Boost::array over a C style array in C++, and +1 on your post.